# `boost::program_options` cannot use `store` twice on `variables_map`

Tags: c++, boost, boost-program-options

I'm trying to edit a `boost::program_options::variables_map` to add implied option according to the first positional option.  However, using `po::store` doesn't work a second time when using it on a `boost::variables_map`.

Here is a minimal example that fails :

```
#include <boost/program_options.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

namespace po = boost::program_options;

std::ostream &operator<<( std::ostream &s, po::variables_map const &vm )
{
    for (const auto& it : vm)
    {
        s << it.first.c_str() << " ";
        auto& value = it.second.value();
        if (auto v = boost::any_cast<char>(&value))
            s << *v;
        else if (auto v = boost::any_cast<short>(&value))
            s << *v;
        else if (auto v = boost::any_cast<int>(&value))
            s << *v;
        else if (auto v = boost::any_cast<long>(&value))
            s << *v;
        else if (auto v = boost::any_cast<std::string>(&value))
            s << *v;
        else if (auto v = boost::any_cast<std::vector<std::string>>(&value))
        {
            s << "[";
            for( const auto &w : *v )
                s << " " << w;
            s << " ]";
        }
        else
            s << "<?>";
        s << '\n';
    }
    return s;
}

int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
    po::options_description  desc("Options");
    desc.add_options()
        ("help","show this help message")
        ("verbose","print extra messages")
        ("dummy","pointless")
        ("dummy-int", po::value< int >(), "pointless")
        ("dummy-str", po::value< std::string >(), "pointless")
    ;

    po::variables_map vm;
    po::store( po::parse_command_line( argc, argv, desc ), vm );
    po::notify( vm );

    bool verbose = vm.count("verbose");

    if( verbose )
        std::cout << vm << std::endl;

    if( vm.count( "help" ) )
    {
        std::cout << desc << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }

    const char* newOption = "--dummy";
    po::store( po::parse_command_line( 1, &newOption, desc), vm );
    po::notify( vm );

    if( verbose )
        std::cout << vm << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Building and running the program, I can see on the terminal :

```
dummy-int 3
verbose 

dummy-int 3
verbose
```

In other words, option `dummy` was *not* stored into `vm` !  Can you help me find why not ?  Thank you for any help !

Comment: Thank you !  You should have said it in an answer so I could mark the question as answered...

Comment: Done :) Removed that comment, since it's now redundant and I noticed I had a typo there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot that the first argument has a special meaning -- it is the name of the program as it was invoked.

According to the [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/main_function):

> `argv[0]` is the pointer to the initial character of a null-terminated multibyte strings that represents the name used to invoke the program itself (or an empty string "" if this is not supported by the execution environment).

In the snippet

```
const char* newOption = "--dummy";
po::store( po::parse_command_line( 1, &newOption, desc), vm );
```

You pass a one element array as `argv`, which means you're not supplying any arguments, and there's nothing for the library to parse. Hence, nothing is added to the `variable_map` instance.